# Animated 3D Scatter-Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, scatter-plot

I have a set of data with a total of 4 independent variables, and I figure the only way to represent 4 independent variables and one dependent variables is to animate a 3D scatter-plot.

Let's say I have the following set of data:

```
W X Y Z Val
0 0 0 0 5.5
0 0 0 1 2.3
0 0 1 0 1.6
0 0 1 1 8.8
0 1 0 0 2.6
0 1 0 1 4.8
0 1 1 0 0.1
0 1 1 1 1.1
1 0 0 0 1.0
1 0 0 1 0.0
1 0 1 0 0.4
1 0 1 1 4.4
1 1 0 0 4.4
1 1 0 1 7.9
1 1 1 0 9.1
1 1 1 1 2.3
```

And the values were read in and converted to the following arrays:

```
W = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
x = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}
X = {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1}
Z = {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}
Val = {5.5,2.3,1.6,8.8,2.6,4.8,0.1,1.1,1.0,0.0,0.4,4.4,4.4,7.9,9.1,2.3}
```

I'm wondering how to create a 3D scatter-plot (scatter3) with X, Y, and Z as the independent variables, Val as represented by the colors of the dots, and to animate with respect with the variable W as time?

Basically, when the different values of Val for when W=0 and W=1 are plotted at different times with respect to X, Y, and Z.

Comment: @natan Sorry, the last sentence was the question. Made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, I have slightly refined my suggestions:

```
mat=cell2mat([W;x;X;Z;Val])'; %Convert cells into a matrix

colors=prism(numel(mat(:,1)));
scatter3(mat(1,2),mat(1,3),mat(1,4),100,colors(1,:),'filled');
axis tight;

for jj=1:8:numel(mat(:,1))
    scatter3(mat(jj:jj+7,2),mat(jj:jj+7,3),...
        mat(jj:jj+7,4),100,colors(jj:jj+7,:),'filled');
    drawnow
    pause(1)
end
```

In the above example the colors are sequentially assigned, but if you want the colors to be the same where VAL is the same, you could do something like the following:

```
mat=cell2mat([W;x;X;Z;Val])';
val_new=mat(:,5)/max(mat(:,5)); %0<VAL<1
scatter3(mat(1,2),mat(1,3),mat(1,4),100,[0 val_new(1) 0],'filled');
axis tight;

for jj=1:8:numel(mat(:,1))
    scatter3(mat(jj:jj+7,2),mat(jj:jj+7,3),...
        mat(jj:jj+7,4),100,[zeros(8,1) val_new(jj:jj+7,:) zeros(8,1)],'filled');
    drawnow
    pause(1)
end
```

Of course, both these examples assume that you will consistently have 8 entries at each time. And in the second instance there will be occasions where the differences in the colors are only very slight. If you want to actually save a video or a animated gif, just take a look at `getframe` and `imwrite`.

Comment: This helps, I'll need to test this. I've also updated my question to be a bit clearer.