# How to slow animatedline rendering time - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a boundary the I wish to scatter plot using animatedline. How can I control/slow the speed of this operation?

Script:

```
clc;
clear;       
I = imread('http://dreamicus.com/data/key/key-01.jpg');
I =   rgb2gray(I);
I=imcomplement(I);
level = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I,level);     
BW_filled = imfill(BW,'holes');     
boundaries = bwboundaries(BW_filled);  
figure,imshow(I);     
b = boundaries{1}; 
plot(b(:,2),b(:,1),'b','LineWidth',2);

an = animatedline; 
x=b(:,2);
y=b(:,1);


for k = 1:numel(x)
  disp(k)
  addpoints(an, x(k), y(k))
  drawnow
  % Wait for 0.1 seconds
  pause(0.1)
end
```

Comment: Have you checked the build-in function: [pause](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated 3D Scatter-Plot in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927621/animated-3d-scatter-plot-in-matlab)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`timer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) object to specify the rate at which new points are added (using `addpoints`)

```
t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
          'Period', 0.1, ...
          'TimerFcn', @(s,e)addSomePoints());

k = 1;

start(t);

function addSomePoints()
    addpoints(an, x(k), y(k))

    % Stop the timer when we're done.
    k = k + 1;
    if k > numel(x)
        stop(t);
    end

    drawnow
end
```

Optionally, you could use [`pause`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) to wait for a certain amount of time after you add each point. This option, however, doesn't take into account how long `addpoints` takes to execute.

```
for k = 1:numel(x)
    addpoints(an, x(k), y(k))

    % Wait for 0.1 seconds
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Comment: updated the script but it still render very fast, why?

Comment: You should change the period to be a larger number so that it renders slower